# Refer link for subscriber user in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to provide a link to subscriber user so that they can refer their link to other users . With that link user redirect to our site and also count as visitor through referral . How I procceed for that in wordpress Any help?

thanks in advance..

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not for requesting some plugin theme releted question. better you go https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and ask . Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: here you find some plugin which can help you https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/referral-program/

Comment: I want to do this through code

Comment: first what you have done so far ? show me

Comment: Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting a question. This is for your benefit too, as it will increase your chance of getting help. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)